# Sensible way to rewrite a field for all views in Drupal 8?

Tags: entities, 8

In Drupal 8 seems one has to create 2 or 3 files plus folder structures to do even the simplest of tasks. So I am trying to figure out how to do a simple hack without all the overhead.

I have a node type for which I attached images. There is a parent node for which I want to display one of the images from the children. I created an Image field for the parent.

So literally, all I need to do is query the database, grab a child's image at random (in every view, each time the parent is viewed, I want the image re-assigned randomly), and rewrite the parent's image field accordingly. This was so easy in Drupal 7...

Does anyone have an idea of how to do this in Drupal 8 in the simplest possible manner, ideally editing just one file?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use hooks the same way as in Drupal 7, if you want to change the content of the node before rendering, you can put a hook in your module or theme:

```
module/theme_preprocess(&$variables, $hook) {
   if ($hook == 'node') {
      ...
```

check if you are in the right node and change it.

The simplest solution for your problem would be to put all children images in the node display and then hide the images you don't want:

```
hide($variables['content']['field_image_?']);
```

So you don't need to lookup the children image yourself.

Comment: Interesting. I just read about twig, and seems twig allows you to specify a filter which perhaps would also be a way to accomplish this. I understand the preprocess approach you mention. Would it also make sense to edit the field directly in the appropriate twig template file?

Comment: Will that work though if View s is doing the rendering? Wouldn't I need to use a Views specific hook?

Comment: Yes, you can do the same with twig, in my project i do lot of image handling in php, twigs and jquery. You can do the task with all of them, but php in a hook seems to be the simpliest way to do it.

Comment: I created a module and the associated yml and module file. I have tried mymodule_preprocess, mymodule_preprocess_views_view, but the functions are not being called. The module is enabled and I cleared cache. Is there any obvious reason why these functions would not be called?

Comment: This depends how you configure the format in view, if you show content, then you can use a node hook, if you show fields you can use a field hook.

Comment: Even mycustom_preprocess_views_view_field isn't getting called. Maybe the way to set up a module in Drupal 8 RC1 is different than what is shown online in tutorials?

Comment: To implement a hook, you only need two files in your module, mymodule.info.yml and mymodule.module, where you put the hook. It should work, if you don't have a syntax or naming problem.

Comment: I think it must be an issue with the views and/or template API. I see this on drupal site:  "views.theme.inc template_preprocess_views_view_fields(&$variables)" but under actual Views hooks, there is no such function. The Views hooks listing has, for insance, "hook_views_pre_render(ViewExecutable $view)"

Prepares variables for views fields templates.

Comment: You don't need a view hook, you can use a normal field hook, this hook is invoked every time a field is rendered, it does not matter, in which context this takes place. But you need to check the context in the hook to avoid that your code is executed at the wrong place.

Comment: I figured out why the call was not happening. Apparently as I make changes to my module file I need to uninstall and then reinstall the module. I thought clearing cache was enough... Thanks for your help!

Comment: It seems regular field hooks do not work. They have to be views field hooks. I just confirmed this by trying both.